# How can I prove that $\frac{\textrm{d}{a}}{\textrm{d}{t}} = 1$ is the same as $\int \textrm{d}{a} = \int \textrm{d}{t}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How is the "treating differentials individually as algebraic elements" step *mathematically* justified (I understand its handwavy algebraic spirit)?

$$\frac{\textrm{d}{a}}{\textrm{d}{t}} = 1$$
$$\textrm{d}{a} = \textrm{d}{t}\quad\text{...the physicists' move}$$
$$\int \textrm{d}{a} = \int \textrm{d}{t}$$

Likely, this question has been answered before on M.SE, but I seem to not be able to find the right keywords to find that answer. What is the above manipulation called?

Comment: yeah you're right it was asked before

Comment: @Shahar can you tell me what I should type in the search bar to find it?

Comment: It was something like how come everything in calculus is so perfectly algebraic?

Comment: At this stage, and perhaps for a long time, a reasonable response is to verify that the possibly meaningless symbol manipulation gives the right answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's the spirit.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Lets say though that I wanted to know the keywords for the subject that studies why differentials can be manipulated like real numbers?

Comment: @user89: Maybe you are looking for something like: Justification for the Method of Separation of Variables at: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~m3cod/klbookLectures/303unit/sep.pdf

Comment: @Amzoti Yes. Thank you. Would you like to write your comment up as an answer?

Comment: @user89: The site typically hates link only answer like that. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am really perplexed by the amount of questions involving "mysterious" nature of 
$$
\frac{da}{dt}.
$$
But there is nothing mysterious here. You start with the equality
$$
\frac{da}{dt}=1
$$
and you integrate both sides with respect to $t$:
$$
\int\frac{da}{dt}dt=\int 1\,dt
$$
After the change of the variable on the left you get your
$$
\int da=\int dt,
$$
which is you were looking for.